# Format the output of List category posts plugin

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I wanted to have the first few lines (say 5 lines) of individual user posts with a particular tag to appear along with their featured image on a particular page.  My search for a plugin to do the same took me to your plugin "List category posts" and found that it does things I want but not in a very formatted and exact manner i want.

1. Though the lines in the posts are separate, the plugin shows everything in single continues line.  Is there a way to display the first few lines from the post as it is? i.e with out combining them into a single line?
2. Is there a way to adjust position of the featured image displayed by List category posts? I use thumbnail=yes to get the pic. I want the pic to be on the left and the text parallel to the right edge of the photo.
3. Is there a way to hide displaying the name of the post?
4. Is there a way to specify the first 'n' lines should be displayed?

Comment: most of what you need can be done in css

Answer (score 0):

since version 0.23, you can define HTML tags and CSS classes for each element. So as Deryk said, you can accomplish most of what you need with CSS.

1. Didnt' really get what you need here, but check the README file, there's lots of customizations you can do.
2. You can set a thumbnail_class and then style it with CSS.
3. You can set an HTML tag and CSS class for the post title with title_tag and title_class, and you could set display:none for the class you used in your CSS.
4. Do you mean first 'n' lines from the post? There's nothing coded for this, but you can use the excerpt and set how many characters to display with excerpt_size